# How do I update the values contained in an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of Particle (a structure) which I am trying to update using a `for` statement.

```
struct Particle {
    private var internalState = 0
    mutating func updateStateWith(_ newState:Int) {
        self.internalState = newState
    }
}

var particles = [Particle]()
particles.append(Particle())
particles.append(Particle())
for var particle in particles {
    particle.updateStateWith(2)
}
```

And the compiler complains that I am trying to update in immutable, that particle is a `let` variable.  I know that I can use `map` by (I hope I'm remembering correctly

```
particles = particles.map {(particle:Particle -> Particle in
    var newParticle = particle
    newParticle.updateStateWith(2)
    return newParticle
}
```

but this feels really clunky.  The `for` version clearly says I wish to update some values in the array without creating new values (or a whole new array).  By the way `Particle` can by a `class` rather than `struct` (i.e. I work with an array of references), and it still complains.

Comment: The code you posted does not generate a compiler error in Xcode 9.2 playground.

Comment: Well, I didn't try the Playground, but 9.2 doesn't like it (in a slightly more complex form, but still) in code.  Let me look....

Comment: If you want call a mutating func, your struct variable needs to be declared as var not let. This is because a new struct is created and assigned to the var when you call a mutating func.

Comment: OK, Mike you are right, it doesn't complain in the playground BUT it doesn't actually update the value (edited my code so that the `particles` array actually contained something).  internalState is still 0, not 2.  So I'm showing my non-Swiftian expectations.  Also, where is the struct variable declared as var?  isn't everything in the code a var rather than let?

Comment: See @Helam's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example given does work. If the code you posted is the full code from your project, you might attempt a clean of the project.

By way of answering the question in the title, after your `for var particle in particles` loop (assuming no compiler error) the particles will not be updated.

Since `struct`s are value types in Swift, each value of `particle` in your loop is a copy of the particle and not a reference to it. You are updating the copy but the original array stays the same.

```
for var particle in particles {
    particle.updateStateWith(2) // updates the copy of the particle
} 
// `particles` remains unchanged
```

If you really want to update an array of `struct`s in a for loop you can do it like this:

```
for i in particles.indices {
    particles[i].updateStateWith(2) // updates actual array element
} 
// `particles` has now been updated
```

Comment: `for i in particles.indices` is a nicer way to do `for i in 0..<particles.count`.

Comment: Right.  I forgot that.  But if I replace the struct with class (and take out the unneeded `mutating` , then it should work, as the array is one of references.  Checking THAT in the playground now gives the correct behavior, though again in my code the compiler still complains.

Comment: @RickShafer I'm guessing there is something in the `slightly more complex form` you mentioned that is causing the compiler error.

Comment: @Helam:  Thanks, though the slightly more complex form is really just a lot more variables in the internal state, and a comparably more complex update.  But I appreciate your timely answer, as that fixes my difficulty.